# How to click on the <a> Login </a>?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

How to click on the below `Login`?

```
<div style="margin: 20px 0; text-align: center;">
<a class="button" href='/aems/login.do'>Login</a>
</div>
```

I wrote the below but got error:

```
driver.find_element(:class, "button").submit
```

***Error***

```
[remote server] file:///C:/DOCUME~1/rakshiar/LOCALS~1/Temp/webdriver-profile2013
0125-6116-rvc0z6/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.
js:8251:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_': Unable to locate elem
ent: {"method":"class name","selector":"button"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::No
```

Please help me here to fix the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'login') and text()='Login']")).click();
```

Comment: Are you sure -contains(@href,'login')? or contains(@href,'/aems/login.do')?

Comment: both are ok contains means you need to provide substring of that href(or any property in tag).

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the `<a>...</a>` and try the script: `document.getElementById(yourid).click()`.

Let me know if you can resolve it.

Comment: This is taken from a `third party application` webpage's source,So i do have read access only. Can't add any element to there webpage source `html`.

Comment: please try to use ：driver.find_element(:class=>"button").click, let me know if it resolve your issue